# Phone gets shutdown

Tags: shutdown, xolo-x900

I have an issue with my Android phone as i cannot run more than one application at a time. If i run it gets switched off unexpectedly. Sometimes even working with 1 application will make my phone get switched off. If it happens i have to wait for 10 minutes to get my phone back again normal. In between if i try to switch on my phone again it will get switch off.

This issue happens when my phone internal storage is full and i thought because of no disk space it happens. I even posted a question about the internal storage space issue.

[Android phone system data is keep eating the space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60023/android-phone-system-data-is-keep-eating-the-space)

But after that I went to recovery mode and repaired my phone and now its like a new phone. I thought all issues got over but after that i found this issue is still there and makes me annoyed everytime it gets shutdown'd by any app. But the interesting fact is this shutdown issue is not happening when the phone is in charge. I can run any number of apps when my phone in charge and it works great.

I have collected log using "Log Collector" app and attached the link below.

[Android Log](http://www.catchmehere.tk/android/log.txt)

Please check the log and help me know which app or settings is making these issues. And also please suggest any upgraded OS if required to reinstall OS in my phone.

### My Phone Specification

Model: Intel Xolo X900
Android OS Version: Android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich
[Manufacturer's site](http://www.xolo.in/x900)

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem, such as your phone's CPU overheating under load, or the battery voltage dropping.

Comment: Well the device is not overheating.. should be the problem with the battery... coz my device has a weird battery which is not removable instead wired with the device.. let me check and get back to you... thank you for the hint...

Comment: How can you be so sure it's not overheating? If there's a manufacturing defect in the heatsink, the CPU might be reaching 90℃ while the outer case only feels slightly warm.

Comment: coz when ever i play game or use heavy app i can feel the heat rising. But this time when the phone gets switched off i cant even feel a slight warm. Well im not very much sure, there may be also defect in CPU.. Let me check...

Comment: im also having the same issue with XOLO x900. It something with Battery voltage. And battery is not removable. HELP PLEASE